# member variable as default argument?

Tags: c++, arguments, default-arguments

I got "a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object" with the following code,

```
class A{
    int data;
    int _default = 0;
public:
    A(int data, int _default) : data(data), _default(_default) {}
    void set(int data = _default){ this->data = data; }
};

int main(){
    A a1(1, 1); a1.set(10); a1.set();
    A a2(2, 2); a2.set(20);
}
```

What I want to do?

- when we call `A.set()`, `A::data` is set to `A::_default`
- when we call `A.set(a)`, `A::data` is set to `a`

Answer (score 6):

Non-static data members can't be used as [default arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments), which are supposed to be provided from the caller side context.

> Non-static class members are not allowed in default arguments (even if they are not evaluated),

You could provide another overload.

```
class A{
    int data;
    int _default = 0;
public:
    A(int data, int _default) : data(data), _default(_default) {}
    void set(int data){ this->data = data; }
    void set(){ set(this->_default); }
};
```

Comment: Before asking this question, I deleted the overload version. Actually,  what I want to do is removing the overloads.

Comment: @LI.LE It's just impossible. Unless making `_default` a `static` member, or call it like `a1.set(a1._default);`.

Comment: @LI.LE consider that default arguments are second class citizens. They arent as nice as one might expect. They are replaced at the call site, ie you cannot use a private member as default

Comment: _"Actually, what I want to do is removing the overloads."_ — Why?

Answer (score 5):

From the 2017 C++ standard, section 11.3.6, para 9

> A non-static member shall not appear in a default argument unless it appears as the
> id-expression of a class member access expression (8.2.5) or unless it is used to form a pointer to member (8.3.1).

All other C++ standards (before and since) have a similar statement, although the wording and section numbers vary.   Neither of the "unless" points in the above are applicable in this case.

It is notionally possible (since C++17) to use `std::optional` (from header `<optional>`) to avoid the overload, as follows.

```
#include <optional>

class A
{
     int data;
     int _default = 0;
   public:
     // other members omitted
   
     void set(std::optional<int> data = std::optional<int>())
     {
         this->data = data.has_value() ? data.value() : _default;
     };
 };
```

or (as suggested by Jarod42 in comments)

```
     void set(std::optional<int> data = std::nullopt)
     {
         this->data = data.value_or(_default);
     };
```

I use the word "notionally" in the above because, personally, I would simply use two overloads.   It is (arguably) easier for a mere mortal to understand and works with all C++ standards (not just since C++17)

```
 void set(int data){ this->data = data; }
 void set(){ set(this->_default); }
```

Comment: [`std::nullopt`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt) and [`optional<T>::value_or`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value_or) might help

Comment: ie. `void set(std::optional<int> arg = std::nullopt) { data = arg.value_or(_default); }`.

Comment: @Jarod42  Yes, that's a viable alternative as well.   I'll edit shortly to note that.

Answer (score 3):

what you can do is you can provide an overload.

```
void set(){ this->data = this->_default; }
void set(int data){ this->data = data; }
```

This will accomplish the job you want to do.